# javascript link not working correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get a simple piece of text displayed as a link. When it is rendered it looks correct eg: http://www.google.com, but the link redirects to my project with the link appended on the end:
http://localhost:8050/brents-test-community/ru61pmlc7vry/groupplaymanager-display/h16wwislnsl/www.google.com, instead of just http://www.google.com.

This what i used:

```
var urlHtml = groupPlay.Url.link(groupPlay.Url);
var url =  document.getElementById('GroupPlayInput_Url');
url.innerHTML = urlHtml;
```

The value of groupPlay.Url is a simply "www.google.com".

And this is the div:

```
<div style="padding-top: 5px;" id="@Html.IdFor(view => view.GroupPlayInput.Url)">
   @if (Model.GroupPlayInput.Url.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
     {
       <a href="@Model.GroupPlayInput.Url" target="_blank">@Model.GroupPlayInput.Url</a>
     }

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `http://` beside your url. This will indicate to the browser that the url is an absolute url (not a relative url).

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/nevgc71g/

Comment: something so simple has had me scratching my head for hours. Thank you!